# Is $\frac{1}{\lfloor \frac{a}{b} \rfloor}=\lceil \frac{b}{a} \rceil$??

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is $\frac{1}{\lfloor \frac{a}{b} \rfloor}=\lceil \frac{b}{a} \rceil$?  assuming  that $\frac{a}{b}>1$.

Comment: Try $a = 5, b = 2$ or so.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, you meant a=2,b=1. Your example is not a contradiction.

Comment: @Galc127 That was added after I made my comment.

Comment: the floor function and ceiling functions are always integers, so to show the equality doesn't hold, all you need to do is find a case where $\lfloor{a/b}\rfloor > 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case $\displaystyle\frac{a}{b}\ge2$ we get $\displaystyle\lfloor{\frac{a}{b}\rfloor}\ge2\Rightarrow\frac{1}{\lfloor{\frac{a}{b}\rfloor}}\le\frac{1}{2}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{b}{a}\le\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow\lceil{\frac{b}{a}\rceil}=1$.